# Existence of a convergent sequence implies that a set is dense

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Prove that, for all $A \subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $1$ implies $2$.

$1$. For every $x \in\mathbb{R}$, there is an infinite sequence $(a_n)$
with each $a_n \in A$, such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=x.$

$2$. $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Seems trivial. What has stumped you?

Comment: What's the definition of density you know?

Comment: Let epsilon greater that 0 be given. Then A is dense in R if for every x in R, there exists an a in A such that |x-a|<epsilon.

Comment: Take $a$ to be $a_n$ with $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: To clarify, "*trivial*" in mathematics does not necessarily mean "easy."  It means "follows almost directly as a result of definitions."  It can sometimes be difficult to remember and understand definitions and how to use them.  However, knowing the definition of dense sets and remembering the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of limits, this is a one-sentence proof and certainly qualifies as being considered "trivial."

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, you're absolutely right, once I laid the definitions out and compared their implications, I got it.